# V-for clicks all buttons instead of just one

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js. I am trying to render check boxes from v-for (which renders correctly) based on an array.

Then I try to render a button beside each check box which opens a multi-select based on the selected index. But every time I click the rendered button, it opens up the multi select across all the checkbox buttons.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <label class='label'>countrys:* </label><br><br>
  <div 
    v-for="(country, index) in countries" 
    class="label" 
    style="display: inline-block;">
    <input 
      type='checkbox' 
      value="country">&nbsp
    {{country.geos}} &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <img 
      class='addIcon' 
      v-bind="country" 
      :key="country.index" 
      style="width: 26px;height: 20px;margin-right: 8px;margin-top: px;margin-left: -25px;margin-bottom:-5px"
      src='../../images/createScreen/addClient@2x.png' 
      @click="makeMarketsActive($event, index)">
    <select multiple v-if="!isHidden">
      <option 
        v-for="(market) in country.markets" 
        v-bind="country">
        {{ market }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
export default {
  name: "Update",
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {    
      countries:[
        {
          "index":0,
          "geos":"America",
          "markets":['a','b','c','d']
        },
        {
          "index":1,
          "geos":"Canada",
          "markets":['a','b']
         },
           "index":2,
           "geos":"Africa",
           "markets":['x','z']
         }
      ],
      isHidden:true
    }
  },
  makeMarketsActive(event, index) {
    this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
  }
```

Expected result : When clicking the image rendered for each checkbox I just want to see the market for each geo and not for all.

Comment: I don't think V-For has anything to do with raising a click event.

Comment: The issue is most likely your variable isHidden.  That looks to be one variable used by each select list.  So once you set it to true, all of the lists show.

Comment: You're missing the opening curly brace for Africa `{ "index": 2 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also don't need the extra function

HTML

```
<div id="app">

  <label class='label'>countries:* </label><br><br>
  <div v-for="(country, index) in countries" class="label" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type='checkbox' value="country">{{country.geos}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <img class='addIcon' v-bind="country" :key="country.index" style="margin-right: 8px;margin-top: px;margin-left: -25px;margin-bottom:-5px" src='https://via.placeholder.com/26x20' v-on:click="country.isVisible = !country.isVisible">
    <select multiple v-show="country.isVisible">
       <option v-for="(market) in country.markets" v-bind="country" >{{ market }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    countries: [{
        "index": 0,
        "geos": "America",
        "markets": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        "isVisible": false
      },
      {
        "index": 1,
        "geos": "Canada",
        "markets": ['a', 'b'],
        "isVisible": false
      }, {
        "index": 2,
        "geos": "Africa",
        "markets": ['x', 'z'],
        "isVisible": false
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I thought the hidden  variable I had would work this way. But I was wrong. If I have to make the multiple select a overlay should I add a Modal?

Comment: I think that is a design decision someone would have to make. I would be indifferent to that part. Based on your current setup, I would swap the `&nbsp;` with some kind of css styling instead at the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as mentioned in comments, you are handling each button state via general property `isHidden`. So you need to add this property to data array:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    countries:[
      {
                "index":0,
                "geos":"America",
                "markets":['a','b','c','d'],
        "isHidden":true
                },
                {
                "index":1,
                "geos":"Canada",
                "markets":['a','b'],
        "isHidden":true
                },
                {"index":2,
                "geos":"Africa",
                "markets":['x','z'],
        "isHidden":true
                }
                ]
  },
  methods: {
   makeMarketsActive(event, index) {
            this.countries[index].isHidden = !this.countries[index].isHidden;
}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label class='label'>countrys:* </label><br><br>
  <div v-for="(country, index) in countries" class="label" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type='checkbox' value="country">&nbsp{{country.geos}} &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

    <img class='addIcon' v-bind="country" :key="country.index" style="width: 26px;height: 20px;margin-right: 8px;margin-top: px;margin-left: -25px;margin-bottom:-5px" src='../../images/createScreen/addClient@2x.png' @click="makeMarketsActive($event, index)">
    <select multiple v-if="!country.isHidden">
                     <option v-for="(market) in country.markets" v-bind="country" >
                    {{ market }}
                         </option>
                        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```